# CloudBlobContainer CreateIfNotExistsAsync vs. CreateIfNotExists

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Can anyone explain the difference between the CreateIfNotExists and CreateIfNotExistsAsync methods of the CloudBlobContainer in Windows Azure? The MSDN documentation just says that the CreateIfNotExistsAsync method

> Returns a task that creates the container if it does not already exist.

And for CreateIfnotExists

> Creates the container if it does not already exist.

So I don't really understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially both of the operations are doing the same thing i.e. `creating a blob container if it does not exist`. The difference is that one is doing asynchronously (`CreateIfNotExistsAsync`) and the other synchronously (`CreateIfNotExists`).

Comment: So then what would be the advantage over the Async vs not the Async in web application?

Comment: I haven't tried the async one myself but I'm guessing you get the advantage of non-blocking code when you use async methods.

Comment: I cannot call CreateIfNotExists() using the Storage.dll version 4.2 in the same means I was when using StorageClient as there are no empty constructors?